# Jekyll: All HTML files in /folder, now forced rendering through /folder/page/. How to change?

Tags: html, ruby, localhost, yaml, jekyll

So I've tried looking here:

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

and here:

[Show pages under one folder in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250939/show-pages-under-one-folder-in-jekyll)

But this doesn't seem to resolve my issues.

So here is the situation:

---

Initially, I had all my Jekyll *.html files living in the /root folder of where I am running Jekyll, this was a bit messy, as there was over 30 *.html files, but when I did this:

```
jekyll build

jekyll serve
```

I would get the site propagating to: `http://0.0.0.0:4000/`

I now moved all the *.html files to a folder called /html (within the project root). When running:

```
jekyll build

jekyll serve
```

My site no longer renders at: `http://0.0.0.0:4000/`

But it renders at: `http://0.0.0.0:4000/html/`

---

I would like to remove the /html part of the URL, but as the above 2 links show, there was no previous question related to this.

Can anybody suggest how I can remove the /html part from my URLs?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so initially your folder structure looked like this, correct?

```
/_layouts/default.html
/css/whatever.css
/index.html
```

---

#### Now to your question:

Do you want to move the HTML files **and nothing else** to the `html` subfolder?
In other words, do you want to do this?

```
/_layouts/default.html
/css/whatever.css
/html/index.html
```

If yes, read [David Jaqcuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260708/6884).
If not, continue reading my answer :-)

---

#### Or is it just that you don't want all your source files cluttering up your root folder?

If yes, you could move **everything** into the `html` subfolder, like this:

```
/html/_layouts/default.html
/html/css/whatever.css
/html/index.html
```

Then you need to tell Jekyll that the `html` folder is the root folder for the site's source files.

To do so, you need to add the following line to [the config file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) *(or create the file if it doesn't exist yet)*:

```
source: html
```

**Important: the config file needs to be in the root folder of your project, even if you move your source files into a subfolder!!**

Then all your source files are in the `html` subfolder, but the generated site will look like this:

```
/_layouts/default.html
/css/whatever.css
/index.html
```

In other words, the URL will still be `http://0.0.0.0:4000/`.

If you want to see an example, you can look at [the source code of my blog](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src):
I'm doing exactly the same there, only that the folder with the source files is called `src`.

Comment: `source` is what I was looking for. literally the first config listed in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

By default, for pages in `/html`, Jekyll will generate a page like `/html/page.html` and so on.

I think you cannot add a permalink [front matter default](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) for a folder, you'll be obliged to set a permalink for each page you put in `/html`.

eg : for `html/page.hmtl`, you'll have to set :

```
---
permalink: page.html
---
```

This is the way without plugin. Otherwise, you can do it with a [Generator plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) that will take all your pages in `/html` and change the all the target permalink.